# Semiconductors : LED

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I got to know that the **threshold voltage for an LED is different for LEDs emitting different colors.** I don't actually know the reason. I searched everything from the Web but didn't get that... Kindly help. Just gimme a hint or clue.

Comment: Okay, here's a hint: a LED emitts its color depending on the semiconductor it is made of, and that's because each semiconductor has its own band structure. A higher gap implies more energy to reach the conduction band. Since $E=h \nu$, it will have a higher frequency.  In other words, different colors = different gap energies.

Comment: And it cleared it! yeah! i love ya! thanks @FGSUZ... and i got it.... ! what you missed and hide! i grasped it....! thanks again